# Free positioning of footnotes/comments

Tags: footnotes, article, revtex

I am writing a paper in which I want the ''normal'' footnotes to appear in the references list as usual, BUT as opposed to them I wish to insert one comment which will appear at the bottom of the first page. My question has two parts:

1. Is it possible to place only one special footnote at the bottom of the page, while all the others go to the references list?
2. Is it possible to place such comment without relating it to a specific location in the text (namely - so that it will not appear as superscript at some specific point in the text, but instead as a general comment)? It doesn't even have to be numbered (in fact - better not numbered).

   - Update: The answer below is good, and it answers my questions for the document class: article. BUT I should stress that: I am using document class: Revtex4-1. This class seems to be incompatible with the "endnotes" package so the solution doesn't work in my case. My question still stand and I'd appreciate help.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Maybe this: `\let\svthefootnote\thefootnote\newcommand\freefootnote[1]{\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{#1}\let\thefootnote\svthefootnote}`

Comment: Thanks, does it require any specific package to work?

Comment: This just handles the unlabeled free footnote.  To get notes to appear at the end of the document rather than at the foot of the page, there is an `endnotes` package (I do not have familiarity with it).

Comment: You may be interested in `titlefoot.sty`.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\svthefootnote\thefootnote
\newcommand\freefootnote[1]{%
  \let\thefootnote\relax%
  \footnotetext{#1}%
  \let\thefootnote\svthefootnote%
}
\textheight 2in
\begin{document}
This is a free footnote%
  \freefootnote{Here is my free footnote, unlabeled here or in text}.
Now for an endnote\endnote{Here is an endnote}.

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wanted the endnotes not as "notes", but in the same list as references, here is a way, basically creating footnote `\cite`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mynotes.bib}
@note{A01,
  note = {This is a footnote. This is a footnote. This is a footnote. 
    This is a footnote. This is a footnote. This is a footnote. }
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{mycites.bib}
@BOOK{author1999book,
title = {Very Informative and Handsome Book},
publisher = {College Town, ST: College University Press},
year = {1999},
author = {First M. Last},
}
@BOOK{test2,
title = {Not So Informative and Handsome Book},
publisher = {College Town, ST: College University Press},
year = {1899},
author = {Last, First M.},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\renewcommand\refname{References and Notes}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\begin{document}
This is a test of a citation\cite{author1999book} and a footnote\cite{A01},
followed by a citation\cite{test2}.
\bibliography{mycites,mynotes}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again! But it doesn't sem to work.. I am using "\documentclass[pre,amsmath,twocolumn,showpacs,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}" and for refrences: \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{./bibliography}. Any idea what can go wrong pls?

Comment: @user1611107 One possibility, based on what you show is you list only a single bibliography file, whereas I placed references and notes in two separate files, so that, in my case, `\bibliography{mycites,mynotes}` calls on both files to be examined for the data.  When you say "doesn't work", be more specific.  Does it compile, but give you `?` for reference numbers?  Does it not compile at all?

Comment: When I dont write "\theendnotes" at the bottom, It compiles, but with the following error message: "! Undefined control sequence. <write> \@doanenote {\@theenmark }.  When I add the line at the bottom, it does not compile at all, instead it says: "! Missing # inserted in alignment preamble... Fatal error occured"

Comment: 1) Is there a way to write it as a macro instead of something which requires a 2'nd file?  2) When I take your example (first code at the top of your answer) as is, but change the documentclass to revtex4-1, it also doesn't compile.

Comment: @user1611107 It would seem the `revtex4-1` document class is incompatible with the `endnotes` package.  I will play with it a bit more, to see if a workaround is possible.

Comment: @user1611107 This fails, indicating `endnotes` is broken by `revtex4-1` : `\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\begin{document}
Hello world\endnote{Here is an endnote}.
\theendnotes
\end{document}`

Comment: I appreciate your help man, thanks a lot. I'm looking to c if it can be done just by using some macrolike "\newcommand{..} or \renewcommand{..}. If I find I'll also upload the solution.